# Weird situation with an arraylist and parallelStream

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have a parallel stream because the task is really slow, I will paste the code below. The situation is this.

I have an arrayList, I need to do something with each object in that list (this is slow) and add the object to a temporal list, the process in the stream ends ok, I think, because I can see each object processed with logs.

When the stream ends, sometimes, the temporal list has n-1 objects or one as null.

Any idea?

With this sample code the errors are not happening, but the logic is the same but without the business logic.

```
public class SampleCode {
    public List<SomeObject> example(List<SomeObject> someObjectList) {
        List<SomeObject> someObjectListTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        someObjectList.parallelStream().forEach(someObject -> {
            List<ExtraData> extraDataList = getExtraData(someObject.getId());
            if (extraDataList.isEmpty()) {
                someObjectListTemp.add(someObject);
            } else {
                for (ExtraData extraData : extraDataList) {
                    SomeObject someObjectTemp = null;
                    someObjectTemp = (SomeObject) cloneObject(someObject);
                    if (extraData != null) {
                        someObjectTemp.setDate(extraData.getDate());
                        someObjectTemp.setData2(extraData.getData2());
                    }
                    if (someObjectTemp == null) {
                        System.out.println("Warning null object"); //I NEVER see this
                    }
                    someObjectListTemp.add(someObjectTemp);
                    System.out.println("Added object to list"); //I Always see this the same times as elements in original list
                }
            }
        });

        if (someObjectListTemp.size() < 3) {
            System.out.println("Error: There should be at least 3 elements"); //Some times one object is missing in the list
        }

        for (SomeObject someObject : someObjectListTemp) {
            if (someObject == null) {
                System.out.println("Error: null element in list"); //Some times one object is null in the list
            }
        }

        return someObjectListTemp;
    }
```

Comment: The code seems like much more than needed to reproduce the problem. Please boil it down to an MCVE

Comment: I posted the exact same algorithm with all the needed classes. I don't see why is too much.

Comment: Please note that you were not asked to post the code that causes your problem but a minimal code that reproduces same result. When you remove code that is not relevant to your problem it helps us understand the problem better. Also often removing the irrelevant code helps you see the problem before you ask us, making your work ´more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to use the [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method instead of `foreach`? 
`flatMap` takes a list of lists and put all their elements in a single list.

This way you do not use another `ArrayList` to store your temporary objects. 
I feel that this might be the issue, because `parallelStream` is multi threading and `ArrayList` is not synchronised

```
List<SomeObject> someObjectListTemp = someObjectList.parallelStream()
    .map(so -> processSomeObject(so)) // makes a stream of lists (Stream<List<SomeObject>>)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) // groups all the elements of all the lists in one stream (Stream<Someobject>)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // transforms the stream into a list (List<SomeObject>)
```

And stick your code in a separate method `processSomeObject` which returns a list of `SomeObject`:

```
static List<SomeObject> processSomeObject(SomeObject someObject) {
    List<ExtraData> extraDataList = getExtraData(someObject.getId());
    List<SomeObject> someObjectListTemp = new ArrayList<>();
    if (extraDataList.isEmpty()) {
        someObjectListTemp.add(someObject);
    } else {
        for (ExtraData extraData : extraDataList) {
            SomeObject someObjectTemp = (SomeObject) cloneObject(someObject);
            if (extraData != null) {
                someObjectTemp.setDate(extraData.getDate());
                someObjectTemp.setData2(extraData.getData2());
            }
            someObjectListTemp.add(someObjectTemp);
            System.out.println("Added object to list");
        }
    }

    return someObjectListTemp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach, but if extraDataList has more than one element I need add to the temporal list someObject clones for each element in extraDataList

Comment: @FranAguiar Ha yes my bad, this can be done with `flatMap`, I will try it out

Comment: @FranAguiar Have a look now, I changed the algorithm to use flatMap seems to work for me

Comment: Thanks, I have been testing this for a while and it works like a charm. I'm so grateful.

Comment: @FranAguiar Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

A small example would be

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 100000).parallel().forEach(i -> test.add(new Object()));
    for(Object o : test) {
        System.out.println(o.getClass());
    }
}
```

i'ts because ArrayList is not threadsafe and the internal array gets screwed